# Plotting CSV with semi-colons and time formatted data with Gnuplot

Tags: csv, plot, visualization, gnuplot

I have 2 CSV files with over 80k strings in each.

The first file have this structure:

```
12.11.12 - 00:59:58;428,8;
12.11.12 - 00:59:59;428,9;
...
12.11.12 - 21:53:32;592,7;
12.11.12 - 21:53:35;596,4;
...
14.11.12 - 12:31:41;510,0;
14.11.12 - 12:31:41;510,0;
```

And the second have another scructure:

```
1;428.9;
1;428.9;
5;428.9;
...
117109;673.6;
117110;672.8;
117111;672.8;
...
214241;497.2;
214241;497.2;
214258;507.3;
```

How I can plot both of this CSV files in Gnuplot?

P.S. The first column must be x and the second must be y.

Comment: What graph do you expect to get for 1st and 2nd file?

Comment: The first column is x and the second is y.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, apparently you can [set the delimiter thus](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/docs_4.2/node173.html):

```
set datafile separator ";"
```

Then [set the time format](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/docs_4.2/node274.html) for your first file, and set x to be a time axis:

```
set timefmt "%d.%m.%y - %H:%M:%S"
set xdata time
```

Plot the first file

```
plot "data1.csv" using 1:2
```

The second file x values don't seem to have a date format, but instead perhaps seconds elapsed? For that, just do

```
set datafile separator ";"
plot "data2.csv" using 1:2
```

and don't `set xdata time`. Then you should have an x axis in seconds. If you need to plot both at the same time, it would be simplest to pre-process one to look like the other.